# Minimum question detail requirements for low rep users

Tags: feature-request

There is a similar question here [What is the minimum complexity required for a question in this community?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/18693/what-is-the-minimum-complexity-required-for-a-question-in-this-community) but it does not propose a solution.

I would like to recommend a minimum "question detail" requirement for users with low rep if they choose certain keywords. So for example if they selected javascript or jQuery as their keywords they have to provide a link to jsfiddle or some other site that demonstrates the problem they are trying to have answered. Or it could just be that their first question for that keyword requires the minimum detail.

This will not only educate first time posters about what tools they should be using but also help other users answer these questions more quickly without having to ask for detail/examples; which I have seen happen time & again. Since the user already has the code it shouldn't take long to configure a jsfiddle.

My first question on SO was terrible, simply because I didn't know what I was doing & what I needed to provide in order for people to help me.

Comment: I think this is a good idea. Low rep users or users with recent down voted questions could be alerted when they try to submit a question and there's no accompanying code/fiddle/link/image. It shouldn't stop them posting as their question may be completely valid but it should at least tell them that they'll get the best responses if they include more detail.

Comment: Just one point, which your title implies but the body doesn't. The minimum detail required for low rep users is no less than that which is required for high rep users. It's just the higher your reputation the more chance you have of getting it right. My problem with this suggestion is that the requirements differ from tag to tag. How would you deal with this?

Comment: @benisuǝqbackwards That would partly be the point of this question... to get suggestions on how to implement it. My suggestion would be to open a meta question for each tag & those who are knowledgeable about technologies linked to the tag contribute. After a deliberation period the question can be closed, moved to the wiki & implemented.

Comment: Maybe not every tag, but for all those that it makes sense to do it to.

Answer (score 3):

I think this can be done by extending the current tag wiki functionality to include an "instruction" section, which will be shown to any user asking the question in that tag for the first (few?) time. This way, the community can provide specific instruction to users new to that tag.

Tag excerpt is currently used for this purpose for some tags. However, I don't know whether people read it or not. In the current design, the tag excerpt is only shown to the user once when they type in the tag. They can access it again by clicking on the tag to bring the tag back in edit mode, but again, I can't think of any reason why people would want to read the tag excerpt again, if they don't read it when the tag excerpt are shown when they are typing in the tag.

Answer (score 2):

I don't believe that (for example) **every** JavaScript or jQuery question should require a link to a service like jsFiddle/jsBin, simply because not every question needs it - same for other tags as well.  Although there are ways that we could improve the quality of new posts (such as being *nice* for once), I don't believe that this will have a dramatic effect on the quality of questions by new users.  For example, take this question (example only):

> ### Help me with my code - document.onkeydown
>
> > Hi my code is not working pls solve this for me: http://jsfiddle.net/deFeA/2
> >
> > i try and fixx dis but it no working can you help me.  i tryed using `document.onkeydown` but it no working so ani help appesiated.  thks
> >
> > is on this line:  `document.onkeydown=html()`
>
> Tags: [javascript](/questions/tagged/javascript) [jquery](/questions/tagged/jquery)

It includes a link to the questioner's jsFiddle, it shows what the problem is and the code with the problem.  However, as we can see, it's an *extremely* low quality question, not one that should be worthy of a high quality answer and probably not one that will help other users in the future.

This affects other tags just as much as this example - forcing a specific thing on a question will only make them work around creating the high quality questions that we love.

Comment: I am not saying EVERY question. I'm saying questions from people who post 1 to 3 lines asking things like "I don't know if this is a good question but I have this thing I want to do please help..." and there is absolutely no supporting code & the question makes no sense what-so-ever. The first thing that is asked: "Can we see some code please".

Comment: At the very least there should be some guide for a tag. Like DB questions... they need a certain level of detail.

Comment: @Precastic: Of course there needs to be a certain level of detail, for any question.  Sometimes though the question isn't something that needs reproduction in a jsFiddle or the type of thing only to occur in a browser environment (or the equivalent for other tags), which is when it's frustrating to have to include a link for the sake of it - which in my opinion would reduce the quality of questions further (harder to tell if question is of very low quality or not).

Comment: Rather than **requiring** user to provide a link, I think it is good to **remind** them along the line *"If applicable, please include a link to jsfiddle and the essential piece of code in your post"*.